# Crystal Report 1997 "Table cannot be found"

Tags: crystal-reports, vb6

I was hoping I could get some help if anyone has came across this issue before for Crystal Report 1997.

I'm currently trying to automate a VB6 program which makes use of Crystal Report 1997.  This process has involved me making use of the Dll `Craxdrt` in order to export the results to PDF.

The problem I'm having is that once I've set the new instance of the `CRAXDRT.Report` to the location where the Crystal report is stored after that any reference to the data source (e.g. the export method or the verify method) will return a message saying:

> `table MyTable cannot be found.  Proceed to remove table?`

Now if I click No on this message box then the report will be generated as a PDF file with the relevant data; if I click Yes then the program will error.

Does anyone know how to stop this message from showing up?

I know on the Crystal Report designer that the table `MyTable` has been set up as a location in the Database menu and that `MyTable` doesn't exist in my database it is an alias used for a global temporary table that is populated and passed to the report via an `SQLQueryString`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer to the query in case anyone else has come across this issue.

I had to programmatically set the data source of the report as well as asigning the SQLQuery variable a value. This resolves the issue going forward.